# wordpress custom function to create table using `WP_List_Table`?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to WordPress. I am trying to create a WordPress table using `WP_List_Table` class. I created a table but it takes a long time. So, I want to create a function that allows me to create a WordPress table, where I can pass data and column array to the function and that function will, then, create the required WordPress table. I want to create table with edit, delete and sort-able functionality.

Comment: Check it out this http://codingbin.com/display-custom-table-data-wordpress-admin/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey try this code it dynamic function but you need to pass first argument kay and name is id.

this is my class that is dynamic create the WP_List_table.

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * Description of wplist_table
 *
 * @author renishkhunt
 */
if (!class_exists('WP_List_Table')) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );
}

class wplist_table extends WP_List_Table
{

    //put your code here
    var $data = array();
    var $default_columns = array();

    public function wplist_table($datad, $columns)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->data = $datad;
        $this->default_columns = $columns;
    }

    function get_columns()
    {

        return $this->default_columns;
    }

    function prepare_items()
    {
        $columns = $this->get_columns();
        $hidden = array();
        $sortable = $this->get_sortable_columns();
        $this->_column_headers = array($columns, $hidden, $sortable);
        usort($this->data, array(&$this, 'usort_recorder'));
        $per_page = 10;
        $current_page = $this->get_pagenum();
        $total_items = count($this->data);

        // only ncessary because we have sample data
        $this->found_data = array_slice($this->data, (($current_page - 1) * $per_page), $per_page);

        $this->set_pagination_args(array(
            'total_items' => $total_items, //WE have to calculate the total number of items
            'per_page' => $per_page                     //WE have to determine how many items to show on a page
        ));
        $this->items = $this->found_data;
    }

    function column_default($item, $column_name)
    {
        foreach ($this->default_columns as $keys => $values) {
            if ($values == $column_name) {
                if(isset($item[$column_name])){
                    return $item[$column_name];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function get_sortable_columns()
    {

        $i=0;
        $sortables = array();
        foreach ($this->default_columns as $keys => $values) {

            if($i == 0){
                $i++;
                //continue;
            }
                $sortables[$keys] = array($values,false);
        }
        return $sortables;
    }

    function usort_recorder($a, $b)
    {
        $orderby = (!empty($_GET['orderby'])) ? $_GET['orderby'] : 'id';

        $order = (!empty($_GET['order'])) ? $_GET['order'] : 'asc';

        $resutl = strcmp($a[$orderby], $b[$orderby]);
        return ( $order === 'asc') ? $resutl : -$resutl;
    }

    function column_Name($item)
    {
        $action = array(
            'edit' => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&fields=%s">Edit</a>', $_REQUEST['page'], 'edit', $item['id']),
            'delete' => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&fields=%s">Delete</a>', $_REQUEST['page'], 'delete', $item['id'])
        );
        return sprintf('%1$s %2$s', $item['name'], $this->row_actions($action));
    }

    function get_bulk_action()
    {
        $actions = array(
            'delete' => 'Delete '
        );
        return $actions;
    }

    function column_db($item)
    {
        return sprintf("<input type='checkbox' name='id[]' value='%s'", $item['id']);
    }

}

?>
```

just you copy that code in file and pass arguments like column name and data like this.

```
  $data = array(
    array("id" => 1, "name" => "Renish Khunt", "add" => "asd"),
    array("id" => 2, "name" => "Renish Khunt", "add" => "asd"),
    array("id" => 3, "name" => "Renish Khunt", "add" => "asd")
);
$columns = array(
    "name" => "name",
    "add" => "add"
);
```

then after create the class object and pass the two arguments the data and column name like this.

```
$mylist_table = new wplist_table($data, $columns);
echo '<div class="wrap"><h2>Custome Fields<a class="add-new-h2" href="?page=' . $_REQUEST['page'] . '&action=add">Add New</a></h2>';
$mylist_table->prepare_items();
$mylist_table->display();
echo "</div>";
```

i hope this is used full for you that is the dynamic class you need to display more column in $column array add column name and $data array add that name of column as key or value like this.

```
$data = array(
array("id" => 1, "name" => "Renish Khunt", "add" => "asd","newcolumn"=>"value"),
array("id" => 2, "name" => "Renish Khunt", "add" => "asd","newcolumn"=>"value"),
array("id" => 3, "name" => "Renish Khunt", "add" => "asd","newcolumn"=>"value")
);
$columns = array(
    "name" => "name",
    "add" => "add",
    "newcolumn"=>"New Column"
);
```

like this i hope this code is used full for you.

thank you.